# Keras costume loss for two connected Autoencoders

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to train two Autoencoders jointly and connect their activation layer in the deepest layer.

How can I add all the terms in one loss function?

Assume:

```
diffLR = Lambda(lambda x: abs(x[0] - x[1]))([model1_act7, model2_act5])
model = Model(inputs=[in1, in2], outputs=[diffLR, model1_conv15, model2_conv10])
model.compile(loss=['MAE', 'mean_squared_error','mean_squared_error'],
          optimizer='SGD',
          metrics=['mae', rmse])

model.fit([x_train_n, y_train_n], [yM1, x_train_n, y_train_n], batch_size=10, epochs=350, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True) #, callbacks=[es])
```

Two networks are convolutional Autoencoders mapping x->x and y->y. Lambda layer connects the latent space of two networks. Target for diffLR is to train the network to the point that two feature spaces represent same distribution. (yM1 is a zero matrix of the same size as latent feature space.)

Now each are optimized separately (or I think they are optimized separately...), I would like to join them in a single loss function like this:

```
def my_loss(z, x, y, z_pred, x_pred, y_pred):
loss = backend.sqrt(backend.mean(backend.square(x_pred-x))) + backend.sqrt(backend.mean(backend.square(y_pred-y))) + backend.sqrt(backend.mean(backend.square(z_pred-z)))
return loss

model.compile(loss=[my_loss],
          optimizer='SGD',
          metrics=['mae', rmse])
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: When passing a list as loss, it should have one entry per model outputs. The model has 3 outputs, but you passed loss=[<function my_loss at 0x7fa3d17f2158>]
```

or

```
model.compile(loss=my_loss,
          optimizer='SGD',
          metrics=['mae', rmse])

TypeError: my_loss() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'y', 'z_pred', 'x_pred', and 'y_pred'
```

Is this possible to do? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

So, what you are doing is performing `RootMeanSquareError` on each of your `n=3` output followed by a weighted sum (same weight in your case).

As the Error message says clearly:

> ValueError: **When passing a list as loss, it should have one entry per
>   model outputs**. The model has 3 outputs, but you passed....

By passing a list of 3 loss function (might be same or different) while compiling your model You can do the same thing what you are doing in your custom loss function. Additionally, you can also define the weight for each individual loss by passing `loss_weights` argument value. moreover, you can do something following:

```
def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return backend.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true))) 

 model.compile(loss=[my_loss, my_loss, my_loss], # you can pass 3 different (custom) loss function as well
          loss_weight=[1.0, 1.0, 1.0], # Default value is 1
          optimizer='SGD',
          metrics=['mae', rmse])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already had the same approach but I had this suspicion that each network is optimized separately, and would not affect the weights in the parallel branches; that's why I wanted to combine all outputs in one loss function. Would backpropagation modify all the weights if I use separate loss functions?